# GCP Organization Policy Exception Condition for One Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

In our GCP Organization, we have a "push" method on service account keys. Currently, there we have an organization policy, constraints/iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation , I would like to keep in place. I see there is a google_organization_policy resource to create your own policy.

Is it possible to create an organization policy to include everybody in this constraint EXCEPT for one designated service account named sa-key-admin@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com created at the organization level. Since GCP does not include IAM as a resource, I do not quite understand how to do this.

If not, is there some type of binding permission to restrict any group / service account from utilizing serviceAccounts.keys.create() permission except for sa-key-admin@<project_id> which can only be impersonated by a specific group?

Thanks!